# Goroutine and for loop

Tags: concurrency, go, parallel-processing, goroutine

All I want to do is to send one value to the channel and return from the `main()` function and exit the program right after I receive one value from the channel `ch`.

But this keeps running forever:

```
ch := make(chan int)

for {
    go func() {
        ch <- 1
    }()
}

<-ch
```

How do I return with this `for` loop after I receive one value from the channel?

And why does this run forever?

Go playground link is here

http://play.golang.org/p/EvmT6Pw96Y

Comment: why are you using for-loop?

Comment: just experimental. I just wanted to launch goroutines and exit the main program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `for` loop runs forever, your code runs forever. Receiving from `ch` after the `for` loop is never reached.

If you want your code to exit sometime, you have to end the `for` loop sometime, e.g. make it run only a certain number of iterations:

```
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    ...
}
```

So if you only run 5 iterations (like in my example), after the `for` loop receiving from `ch` will be executed which may block (because `ch` is unbuffered) if other goroutines have not yet run, and at least one of the started goroutines will be executed which sends a value on the channel which may trigger the main goroutine to continue (because its blocking operating is no longer blocking).

Also note that the [**Go Memory Model**](http://golang.org/ref/mem) only guarantees that certain events happen before other events, you have no guarantee how 2 concurrent goroutines are executed. You have no guarantee that the goroutines started in the `for` loop will start to execute before the main goroutine gets blocked at receiving from `ch`.

Usually when a goroutine gets blocked (e.g. blocking channel receive operation), the runtime may schedule another goroutine to run.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking one of the first goroutine within for-loop gets launched in the back ground and if I receive one from them, the main would exit.

Comment: The read from the channel is never reached because the main routine is spinning in an infinite loop launching an infinite amount of corroutines. This program should crash with out of memory or freeze your computer after a few seconds as it allocates memory all the time.